# Usar :before ou um div com uma imagem?

Tags: html, css

Estou terminando um site e não sei se uso `:before` ou uma `div` com o *background* da imagem, o que eu preciso é disso:

[image]

Como podem ver, são 2 `divs`, a primeira é a do óculos, e a segunda é a do texto, eu tentei fazer um `:before` para ter esse triângulo, mas nao deu certo, quando a resolução muda fica ruim, porque o site é responsivo, então, o que eu faço? Crio uma `div` antes ou uso `:before` mesmo?

O site [está no ar](http://www.planow.com.br/eco/colecoes.php), é so selecionar uma coleção que vai aparecer este conteúdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separei por div's cada elemento para uma melhor organização e melhor manutenção futura. Fica mais ou menos assim ("div do fundo", "div da img" e "div do texto")

**Exemplo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/69PLK/1/

Ai está um exemplo que ta com as formatações dos textos de exemplo boviamente.. mas a ideia é essa!